# Python and java static IP

Tags: java, python, sockets, tcp, ip

I have a Python server. Each time I change the network the IP changes. I want it to have a static IP over all networks so it can receive data without customizing the code every time.
I want to do the same for a Java server too.

Comment: This has nothing to do with programming but your network settings. http://serverfault.com/ might be a better place to ask.

Comment: @Selcuk Thanks buddy. I will ask there.

Answer (score 0):

You may talk with your ISP to rent a static IP address, although I would recommend using name instead of IP address. Means, trust a DNS server to translate the IP to the name and and thus even if the IP is changing, it will give the new IP each time. How? well there are free online name services (such as "no-ip") that you can register your IP each time, to a fixed name address.